# How to turn a DbSet into a dropdown list, for example?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to wrap my head around all of this ViewModel stuff and do things the right way. I have several models linked to SQL tables via Entity Framework, like this one:

```c#
[Table("HardwareOptions", Schema = "dbo")]
public class HardwareOption {
  [Key]
  public int RecordID {get; set;}
  [ForeignKey("Configuration")]
  public string Configuration {get; set;}
  public string ComputerManufacturer {get; set;}
  public string ComputerModel {get; set;}
  public string ComputerDescription {get; set;}
  public int MonitorCount {get; set;}
  public string MonitorManufacturer {get; set;}
  public string MonitorModel {get; set;}
  public string MonitorDescription {get; set;}
}
```

I have a view model like this:

```c#
public class OrderIndexViewModel {
  public Customer Customer {get; set;}
  public MetaUser MetaUser {get; set;}
  public DbSet<HardwareOption> HardwareOptions {get; set;}
  public DbSet<Machine> Machines {get; set;}
  public DbSet<PendingOrder> PendingOrders {get; set;}
}
```

And a bit of my controller like this:

```c#
private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
OrderIndexViewModel viewmodel = new OrderIndexViewModel();
viewmodel.Customer = db.Customers.Find("myselffortesting");
viewmodel.MetaUser = db.MetaUsers.Find("myselffortesting");
viewmodel.HardwareOptions = db.HardwareOptions;
viewmodel.Machines = db.Machines;
viewmodel.PendingOrders = db.PendingOrders;
return View(viewmodel);
```

So as you can see, in my view, I only need information about one customer/user, but I need to be able to query the entire HardwareOptions, Machines, and PendingOrders tables. Now, if my architecture is entirely wrong, please tell me, because that is more what this question is about. But for something specific, say I want to make a dropdown list from HardwareOptions. Technically, I want each `SelectItem` to say a string combination of the values of several columns, but for now I'll say I just want one, like Configuration. What is the right way to do that? I don't know how to manipulate the `DbSet`. When I tried to make a `Html.DropDownList` from the `DbSet`, I got a list with the correct number of items, but they all said "mynamespace.Models.HardwareOption." Which makes sense, I just can't figure out how to do it right.

Comment: the title of your question is very non-specific.  please replace it with a specific question :)

Comment: Is this a question about DB Design or about useful things with DBSets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The useful thing you can do with a `DbSet<T>` in your example is a *projection*. You would define a second ViewModel that contains the properties you want to show in the dropdown list:

```
public class HardwareOptionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Configuration { get; set; }
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Instead of the `DbSet` you are using a collection of this ViewModel in your `OrderIndexViewModel`:

```
public class OrderIndexViewModel
{
    //...
    public IEnumerable<HardwareOptionViewModel> HardwareOptions { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

And only load those properties from the database using a `Select` method:

```
viewmodel.HardwareOptions = db.HardwareOptions
    .Select(h => new HardwareOptionViewModel
    {
        Id = h.Id,
        Configuration = h.Configuration,
        AnotherProperty = h.AnotherProperty,
        //...
    })
    .ToList();
```

**Edit**

You would bind the collection to a dropdown list like so:

```
@model MyNamespace.OrderIndexViewModel

...

<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrentHardwareOptionId,
        new SelectList(Model.HardwareOptions, "Id", "Configuration",
                       Model.CurrentHardwareOptionId))
</div>
```

Here I have introduced a new property `CurrentHardwareOptionId` on `OrderIndexViewModel` that has the same type as the `Id` (`int` in the example) and that is supposed to be the property that the selected `Id` in the dropdown list is supposed to bind to when the page is posted back:

```
public class OrderIndexViewModel
{
    //...

    public int CurrentHardwareOptionId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Minor addition: don't forget to either override the view model's `ToString` method, or don't display the HardwareOptionViewModel objects directly, or you'll still get a dropdown list consisting only of "(namespace).HardwareOptionViewModel" entries.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need almost every property of HardwareOptions, so isn't that kind of redundant? Could you include an example of the call to `Html.DropDownList` or `Html.DropDownListFor`? Does the `SelectList` have to be made from an `IEnumerable<T>` or can I do something with a `DbSet<T>`? Thanks again.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks! That was a big part of my confusion.

Comment: @Andrew: See my Edit above about dropdown example. Direcly using `DbSet<T>` would probably work too if you need *all* properties. It is only considered as not the best practice to let the view rendering execute the query, instead of the controller (`ToList()`) or a repository or service or something.